# How to programmatically force a break in the VBE Editor

Tags: c#, vba, vbe

I am writing a c# application that opens a number of PI ProcessBook display files.  PI Processbook is a program that has embedded Visual Basic for Applications support, including a VBE environment.

The problem that I have is that a number of the displays I want to open have macros in them that run automatically when the display is opened.  I have set the macro protection to maximum (which should disable macros completely!), but unfortunately there is something in the TypeLibrary that I am using that means that when a file is opened programatically, it bypasses macro security and the macros run anyway.  Go figure....

I am therefore trying to find a way to programatically kill these macros, even if they have started.  I have tried using SendKeys.Wait("^{BREAK}") to force into break mode.  This "works", but is a bit hit-and-miss:  I find that if the macro doesn't pause at some point, SetForegroundWindow can't force the VB Editor to the foreground to accept the sendkeys input.  I therefore tried using sendmessage.  I used SPY++ to see that CTRL+BREAK appears to send a WM_CANCELMODE message to the window.  Apparently, this is somehow handled differently from literally ALT+Tabbing or clicking on the window with a mouse and pressing the CTRL+Break keys, in that the message gets queued, but does not appear to process until the macro has finished executing.

Does anyone have any other suggestions of things to try?

Comment: Do the PI ProcessBlock have an `OnDocumentOpen` (or similar) event??
With luck, that application event is fired before the display OnOpen event.
If so, you can edit the document and remove the macros if you find a `VBAProject` (or similar) property somewhere in the document.

Comment: Oooh!  It does!  It has a DisplayOpen() event.  Not sure how to map an event handler to this, but I could give it a go.

Comment: You could also try programatically to disable macros before opening any document.

Comment: @Daniel how do you `programatically disable macros before opening any document`?

Comment: @JeremyThompson I'm not used to PI ProcessBook, so, I'm just suggesting somethings he could try. If the API exposes some functionality to disable macros, it will probably be in the application object instead of in the documents.

Comment: I was able to hook-in to the OpenDisplay event.  I was wondering if it would be possible to OVERRIDE this event.  Anyone know?

Answer (score -1):

> I am therefore trying to find a way to programatically kill these
>   macros, even if they have started.

Hold down the Shift key while opening the Spreadsheet and the Macro's wont run.

Otherwise you could try halting the code while its running: `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `PauseBreak`

**Edit:**

> I have set the macro protection to maximum (which should disable
>   macros completely!)

Try disabling them:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - but I want to do this progamatically.  I have several hundred of these displays to open and process, and I want to do it "hands off".  And please note that this is a program called "PI ProcessBook" which has a VB Editor - it is not actually Excel.